# Can int_leastN_t and int_fastN_t have padding bits?

Tags: c, integer, language-lawyer, padding, c11

Can `int_leastN_t` and `int_fastN_t` have padding bits?

Since both C11, 7.20.1.2 Minimum-width integer types and C11, 7.20.1.3 Fastest minimum-width integer types do not have "no padding bits", then I conclude that `int_leastN_t` and `int_fastN_t` can have padding bits. Is that correct?

Comment: If you use `int_fast8_t` on a 32 bit system and get a 32 bit type, what would you call the 24 bits not containing your value? There is as far as I know no requirement that the compiler would use these for sign extension etc - they might as well be dummy padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, only `(u)intN_t` and `unsigned char` are specified pad-less.

Padding in any integer type is rare these days.